# sqoop2 rest api is not working : NullPointerException

Tags: rest, hadoop, nullpointerexception, sqoop, sqoop2

I am using sqoop 1.99.7, hadoop 2.7.2

firstly, when I requested to "/sqoop/v1/link" with json("http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.7/dev/RESTAPI.html#v1-link-post-create-link"), I met "links" key missing error. so I tried to get link informaion. and I used json structure that when I got from 'get link rest api'. but I am getting NullPointException

this

```
2016-11-02 13:27:32,395 ERROR [org.apache.sqoop.server.SqoopProtocolServlet.doPost(SqoopProtocolServlet.java:70)] Exception in POST http://192.168.44.135:12000/sqoop/v1/link
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:136)
        at org.apache.sqoop.utils.UrlSafeUtils.urlDecode(UrlSafeUtils.java:46)
        at org.apache.sqoop.model.MStringInput.restoreFromUrlSafeValueString(MStringInput.java:62)
        at org.apache.sqoop.json.util.ConfigInputSerialization.restoreConfig(ConfigInputSerialization.java:274)
        at org.apache.sqoop.json.util.ConfigInputSerialization.restoreConfigs(ConfigInputSerialization.java:188)
        at org.apache.sqoop.json.LinkBean.restoreLink(LinkBean.java:145)
        at org.apache.sqoop.json.LinkBean.restoreLinks(LinkBean.java:137)
        at org.apache.sqoop.json.LinkBean.restore(LinkBean.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.handler.LinkRequestHandler.createUpdateLink(LinkRequestHandler.java:116)
        at org.apache.sqoop.handler.LinkRequestHandler.handleEvent(LinkRequestHandler.java:65)
        at org.apache.sqoop.server.v1.LinkServlet.handlePostRequest(LinkServlet.java:71)
        at org.apache.sqoop.server.SqoopProtocolServlet.doPost(SqoopProtocolServlet.java:65)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:554)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and i found out some api in document is not working

like

- get connectors
- get links

and i think more..

is this my problem? how can i fix this?

add: shell is work fine